# key of generic ZodObject

Tags: typescript, validation, zod

I want to create zod schema useing generics

```
export const Paginationn = <T extends AnyZodObject>(valueSchema: T) => {
    z.object({
        page: z.number().default(1),
        pageSize: z.number().default(100),
        sort: z.enum(["asc", "desc"]).default("desc"),
        sortBy: valueSchema.keyof(),
    });
};
```

> sortBy is z.ZodEnum of never

```
type PaginationType<TType extends z.AnyZodObject> = ReturnType<
    typeof Pagination<TType>
>;

export type Pagination<T> = z.infer<PaginationType<z.AnyZodObject>>;

let pagination: Pagination<Employee> = {
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 100,
    sortBy: EmployeeSchema.keyof().enum.name,
    sort: "asc",
};
```

so how can assign a value to it
as error => Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'